# Jimny problem after service

Tags: engine, suzuki

After my normal service of Jimny 2007, I have noticed that when engine is cold and during idle the rpm drops and looks like the engine wiill stop. I have also noticed that I do not hear any more a mechanical noice that I used to hear every time I swich on my Jimny that lasted for 1 sec. Any idea ?

Comment: The only idea I have is for you to take it back to who serviced it and ask them to make it correct. As far as the "*mechanical noise*", there is no way for us to know what you are referring to. Adding details would help a lot.